# How can you use Spring Boot validation annotations with Jackson Custom Deserialization?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So basically, I have JSON payload that I want to deserialize into an custom object. To do this I'm using JacksonDeserializer. I'm also using Spring Validation Annotations to validate fields. Is there a way I get to the Spring Validation inside the deserializer so I can return appropriate exceptions/errors.

Comment: Please provide code samples to better illustrate your need.

Comment: You can use a class that extends jackson objectmapper and use validation in override mothod